AWS Emr Map Reduce job logs are in stderr
I'm running a MR job in EMR and all my logs are in stderr section (when I go into the Job logs from the Resource Manager UI). How can I move them to stdout or syslog ?

I believe, its designed this way to have logs in stderr. You can redirect the spark-submit output to desired log file as well if you need to customize it.

I found the issue. The logger configuration had been set to print the logs at System.err instead of System.out. After I changed this property at the logging framework level (log4j, logback, simplelogger, etc - whatever you're using) my logs were printed in stdout.
